# Trying to make the pin move after my mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a pin slider so that when I click on the pin and move it, the effect is applied to the picture. The problem is that when I'm clicking on the pin, it jumps away and doesn't work properly. If you can, please help me solve this issue!

Sorry for such a huge snippet, the problem is in the JS code that starts with 'pinLevel.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt) { ....'

```js
'use strict';

var COMMENTS_LIST = [
  'Всё отлично!',
  'В целом всё неплохо. Но не всё.',
  'Когда вы делаете фотографию, хорошо бы убирать палец из кадра. В конце концов это просто непрофессионально.',
  'Моя бабушка случайно чихнула с фотоаппаратом в руках и у неё получилась фотография лучше.',
  'Я поскользнулся на банановой кожуре и уронил фотоаппарат на кота и у меня получилась фотография лучше.',
  'Лица у людей на фотке перекошены, как будто их избивают. Как можно было поймать такой неудачный момент?!'
];
var NAMES_LIST = ['Sam', 'Jack', 'Clive', 'Mathew', 'Alex', 'Karl'];
var ESC_KEYCODE = 27;

var template = document.querySelector('#picture').content.querySelector('a');
var picturesDomElement = document.querySelector('.pictures');
var uploadPicLabel = document.querySelector('#upload-file');
var uploadOverlay = document.querySelector('.img-upload__overlay');
var closeOverlay = document.querySelector('.img-upload__cancel');
var previewPic = document.querySelector('.img-upload__preview');
var effectBar = document.querySelector('.img-upload__effect-level');
var effectsFieldset = document.querySelector('.img-upload__effects');
var commentField = document.querySelector('.text__description');
var hashtagsField = document.querySelector('.text__hashtags');
var pinLevel = document.querySelector('.effect-level__pin');
var effectLevelLine = document.querySelector('.effect-level__line');
var effectLevelDepth = document.querySelector('.effect-level__depth');

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var getRandomCommentator = function () {
  var randomCommentator = {};
  var randomComment = COMMENTS_LIST[Math.floor(Math.random() * COMMENTS_LIST.length)];
  var randomName = NAMES_LIST[Math.floor(Math.random() * NAMES_LIST.length)];
  randomCommentator.avatar = 'img/avatar-' + getRandomInt(1, 6) + '.svg';
  randomCommentator.message = randomComment;
  randomCommentator.name = randomName;
  return randomCommentator;
};

var generateComments = function () {
  var randomInt = getRandomInt(1, 26);
  var comments = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < randomInt; i++) {
    comments.push(getRandomCommentator(6));
  }
  return comments;
};

var generateData = function (count) {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    data.push(
        {
          url: 'photos/' + (i + 1) + '.jpg',
          likes: getRandomInt(1, 26),
          comments: generateComments()
        }
    );
  }
  return data;
};

var renderPhotos = function (array) {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
    var element = template.cloneNode(true);
    var item = array[k];
    element.querySelector('.picture__comments').textContent = item.comments.length;
    element.querySelector('.picture__likes').textContent = item.likes;
    element.querySelector('.picture__img').src = item.url;
    fragment.appendChild(element);
  }
  picturesDomElement.appendChild(fragment);
};

var onPopupEscPress = function (evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode === ESC_KEYCODE && document.activeElement !== commentField && document.activeElement !== hashtagsField) {
    closePicEditor();
  }
};

var openPicEditor = function () {
  uploadOverlay.classList.remove('hidden');
  document.addEventListener('keydown', onPopupEscPress);
};

var closePicEditor = function () {
  uploadOverlay.classList.add('hidden');
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', onPopupEscPress);
};

uploadPicLabel.addEventListener('change', function () {
  openPicEditor();
  changeOverlay();
});

closeOverlay.addEventListener('click', function () {
  closePicEditor();
});

var validateCommentLength = function () {
  if (commentField.value.length > 140) {
    commentField.style.border = 'thick solid red';
    commentField.setCustomValidity('The message is too long');
  } else {
    commentField.style.border = '';
    commentField.setCustomValidity('');
  }
};

var changeOverlay = function (percentage) {
  var checkedEffect = effectsFieldset.querySelector('input:checked');
  var filterValue;
  effectBar.classList.remove('hidden');
  switch (checkedEffect.value) {
    case 'chrome': filterValue = 'grayscale(' + percentage + ')'; break;
    case 'sepia': filterValue = 'sepia(' + percentage + ')'; break;
    case 'marvin': filterValue = 'invert(' + percentage + ')'; break;
    case 'phobos': filterValue = 'blur(' + percentage + 'px)'; break;
    case 'heat': filterValue = 'brightness(' + percentage + ')'; break;
    default: {
      filterValue = 'none';
      effectBar.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }
  pinLevel.style.left = percentage + '%';
  effectLevelDepth.style.width = percentage + '%';
  previewPic.style.filter = filterValue;
};

pinLevel.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var startCoords = evt.clientX;
  var onMouseMove = function (moveEvt) {
    moveEvt.preventDefault();
    var shift = moveEvt.clientX - startCoords;
    var newEffectLevel = startCoords + shift;
    var percentageLevel = newEffectLevel / effectLevelLine.getBoundingClientRect().right * 100;
    if (newEffectLevel >= effectLevelLine.getBoundingClientRect().left &&
     newEffectLevel <= effectLevelLine.getBoundingClientRect().right) {
      pinLevel.style.left = percentageLevel + '%';
      effectLevelDepth.style.width = percentageLevel + '%';
      changeOverlay(percentageLevel);
    }
  };
  var onMouseUp = function (upEvt) {
    upEvt.preventDefault();
    startCoords = upEvt.clientX;
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
  };
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
});

var photos = generateData(25);
renderPhotos(photos);
effectsFieldset.addEventListener('click', changeOverlay);
effectsFieldset.addEventListener('click', function () {
  changeOverlay(100);
});
commentField.addEventListener('change', validateCommentLength);
```

```css
/**
 * Шкала регулирования глубины фильтра
 */

.effect-level {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;

  width: 495px;
  height: 33px;

  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  white-space: nowrap;

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 33px;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.effect-level__value {
  display: none;
}

.effect-level__line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;

  height: 5px;

  font-size: 0;

  background-color: rgba(255, 231, 81, 0.4);

  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.effect-level__pin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  z-index: 1;

  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: -9px 0 0;

  background-color: #ffe753;
  border-radius: 50%;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);

  cursor: move;
}

.effect-level__depth {
  position: absolute;

  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: #ffe753;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>Кекстаграм</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>

    <!-- Фильтрация изображений от других пользователей -->
    <section class="img-filters  img-filters--inactive  container">
      <h2 class="img-filters__title  visually-hidden">Фильтр фотографий</h2>
      <form class="img-filters__form" action="index.html" method="get" autocomplete="off">
        <button type=button class="img-filters__button  img-filters__button--active" id="filter-popular">Популярные</button>
        <button type=button class="img-filters__button" id="filter-new">Новые</button>
        <button type=button class="img-filters__button" id="filter-discussed">Обсуждаемые</button>
      </form>
    </section>

    <!-- Контейнер для изображений от других пользователей -->
    <section class="pictures  container">
      <h2 class="pictures__title  visually-hidden">Фотографии других пользователей</h2>

      <!-- Поле для загрузки нового изображения на сайт -->
      <section class="img-upload">
        <div class="img-upload__wrapper">
          <h2 class="img-upload__title  visually-hidden">Загрузка фотографии</h2>
          <form class="img-upload__form" id="upload-select-image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

            <!-- Изначальное состояние поля для загрузки изображения -->
            <fieldset class="img-upload__start">
              <input type="file" id="upload-file" class="img-upload__input  visually-hidden" name="filename" required>
              <label for="upload-file" class="img-upload__label  img-upload__control">Загрузить</label>
            </fieldset>

            <!-- Форма редактирования изображения -->
            <div class="img-upload__overlay  hidden">
              <div class="img-upload__wrapper">
                <div class="img-upload__preview-container">

                  <!-- Изменение размера изображения -->
                  <fieldset class="img-upload__scale  scale">
                    <button type="button" class="scale__control  scale__control--smaller">Уменьшить</button>
                    <input type="text" class="scale__control  scale__control--value" value="55%" title="Image Scale" name="scale" readonly>
                    <button type="button" class="scale__control  scale__control--bigger">Увеличить</button>
                  </fieldset>

                  <!-- Предварительный просмотр изображения -->
                  <div class="img-upload__preview">
                    <img src="img/upload-default-image.jpg" alt="Предварительный просмотр фотографии">
                  </div>

                  <!-- Изменение глубины эффекта, накладываемого на изображение -->
                  <fieldset class="img-upload__effect-level  effect-level">
                    <input class="effect-level__value" type="number" name="effect-level" value="20">
                    <div class="effect-level__line">
                      <div class="effect-level__pin" tabindex="0">Кнопка изменения глубины эффекта фотографии</div>
                      <div class="effect-level__depth">Глубина эффекта фотографии</div>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>

                  <!-- Кнопка для закрытия формы редактирования изображения -->
                  <button type="reset" class="img-upload__cancel  cancel" id="upload-cancel">Закрыть</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Наложение эффекта на изображение -->
                <fieldset class="img-upload__effects  effects">
                  <ul class="effects__list">
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-none" value="none">
                      <label for="effect-none" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--none">Превью фото без эффекта</span>
                        Оригинал
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-chrome" value="chrome">
                      <label for="effect-chrome" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--chrome">Превью эффекта Хром</span>
                        Хром
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-sepia" value="sepia">
                      <label for="effect-sepia" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--sepia">Превью эффекта Сепия</span>
                        Сепия
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-marvin" value="marvin">
                      <label for="effect-marvin" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--marvin">Превью эффекта Марвин</span>
                        Марвин
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-phobos" value="phobos">
                      <label for="effect-phobos" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--phobos">Превью эффекта Фобос</span>
                        Фобос
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-heat" value="heat" checked>
                      <label for="effect-heat" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--heat">Превью эффекта Зной</span>
                        Зной
                      </label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </fieldset>

                <!-- Добавление хэш-тегов и комментария к изображению -->
                <fieldset class="img-upload__text text">
                  <input class="text__hashtags" name="hashtags" placeholder="#хэш-тег">
                  <textarea class="text__description" name="description" placeholder="Ваш комментарий..."></textarea>
                </fieldset>

                <!-- Кнопка для отправки данных на сервер -->
                <button type="submit" class="img-upload__submit" id="upload-submit">Опубликовать</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!-- Здесь будут изображения других пользователей -->

    </section>

    <!-- Полноэкранный показ изображения -->
    <section class="big-picture  overlay  hidden">
      <h2 class="big-picture__title  visually-hidden">Просмотр фотографии</h2>
      <div class="big-picture__preview">

        <!-- Просмотр изображения -->
        <div class="big-picture__img">
          <img src="img/logo-background-3.jpg" alt="Девушка в купальнике" width="600" height="600">
        </div>

        <!-- Информация об изображении. Подпись, комментарии, количество лайков -->
        <div class="big-picture__social  social">
          <div class="social__header">
            <img class="social__picture" src="img/avatar-1.svg" alt="Аватар автора фотографии" width="35" height="35">
            <p class="social__caption">Тестим новую камеру! =)</p>
            <p class="social__likes">Нравится <span class="likes-count">356</span></p>
          </div>

          <!-- Комментарии к изображению -->
          <div class="social__comment-count">5 из <span class="comments-count">125</span> комментариев</div>
          <ul class="social__comments">
            <li class="social__comment">
              <img class="social__picture" src="img/avatar-4.svg" alt="Аватар комментатора фотографии" width="35" height="35">
              <p class="social__text">Мега фото! Просто обалдеть. Как вам так удалось?</p>
            </li>
            <li class="social__comment">
              <img class="social__picture" src="img/avatar-3.svg" alt="Аватар комментатора фотографии" width="35" height="35">
               <p class="social__text">Да это фоташоп!!!!!!!!</p>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Кнопка для загрузки новой порции комментариев -->
          <button type="button" class="social__comments-loader  comments-loader">Загрузить еще</button>

          <!-- Форма для отправки комментария -->
          <div class="social__footer">
            <img class="social__picture" src="img/avatar-6.svg" alt="Аватар комментатора фотографии" width="35" height="35">
            <input type="text" class="social__footer-text" placeholder="Ваш комментарий...">
            <button type="button" class="social__footer-btn" name="button">Отправить</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Кнопка для выхода из полноэкранного просмотра изображения -->
        <button type="reset" class="big-picture__cancel  cancel" id="picture-cancel">Закрыть</button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer class="page-footer  container">
    <div class="page-footer__wrapper">
      <div class="page-footer__copyright  copyright">
        <a class="copyright__link  copyright__link--image" href="https://htmlacademy.ru/intensive/javascript"><img src="img/htmla-logo.svg" width="130" height="45" alt="HTML Academy"></a>
        <p>Сделано в <a class="copyright__link  copyright__link--text" href="https://htmlacademy.ru/intensive/javascript">HTML Academy</a> &copy; 2018</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="page-footer__contacts  contacts">
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/htmlacademy_ru" class="contacts__link  contacts__link--twitter">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/htmlacademy/" class="contacts__link  contacts__link--instagram">Instagtam</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/htmlacademy" class="contacts__link  contacts__link--facebook">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://vk.com/htmlacademy" class="contacts__link  contacts__link--vk">VK</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Шаблон изображения случайного пользователя -->
  <template id="picture">
    <a href="#" class="picture">
      <img class="picture__img" src="" width="182" height="182" alt="Случайная фотография">
      <p class="picture__info">
        <span class="picture__comments"></span>
        <span class="picture__likes"></span>
      </p>
    </a>
  </template>

  <!-- Сообщение с ошибкой загрузки изображения -->
  <template id="error">
    <section class="error">
      <div class="error__inner">
        <h2 class="error__title">Ошибка загрузки файла</h2>
        <div class="error__buttons">
          <button type="button" class="error__button">Попробовать снова</button>
          <button type="button" class="error__button">Загрузить другой файл</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </template>

  <!-- Сообщение об успешной загрузке изображения -->
  <template id="success">
    <section class="success">
      <div class="success__inner">
        <h2 class="success__title">Изображение успешно загружено</h2>
        <button type="button" class="success__button">Круто!</button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </template>

  <!-- Экран загрузки изображения -->
  <template id="messages">
    <div class="img-upload__message  img-upload__message--loading">Загружаем...</div>
  </template>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To fix it:**
[image]

```
  var onMouseMove = function (moveEvt) {
    moveEvt.preventDefault();
    //get the total width of "effectLevelLine"
    var effectTotalWidth = effectLevelLine.offsetWidth;
    //get the start position of "effectLevelLine" from
    var effectLevelStart = effectLevelLine.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    //calculate the shift =  effectLevelLine position - effect-level__pin moveEvt.clientX
    var shift = effectTotalWidth - (effectLevelStart - moveEvt.clientX);
    //calculate percent
    var percentageLevel = shift / effectTotalWidth * 100;
    //to make sure that the pin is inside the effectLevelLine
    if (shift > 0 && shift < effectTotalWidth) {
      //apply 
      pinLevel.style.left = percentageLevel + '%';
      effectLevelDepth.style.width = percentageLevel + '%';
      changeOverlay(percentageLevel);
    }
  };
```

**Note** : explanation in code comment

```js
'use strict';

var COMMENTS_LIST = [
  'Всё отлично!',
  'В целом всё неплохо. Но не всё.',
  'Когда вы делаете фотографию, хорошо бы убирать палец из кадра. В конце концов это просто непрофессионально.',
  'Моя бабушка случайно чихнула с фотоаппаратом в руках и у неё получилась фотография лучше.',
  'Я поскользнулся на банановой кожуре и уронил фотоаппарат на кота и у меня получилась фотография лучше.',
  'Лица у людей на фотке перекошены, как будто их избивают. Как можно было поймать такой неудачный момент?!'
];
var NAMES_LIST = ['Sam', 'Jack', 'Clive', 'Mathew', 'Alex', 'Karl'];
var ESC_KEYCODE = 27;

var template = document.querySelector('#picture').content.querySelector('a');
var picturesDomElement = document.querySelector('.pictures');
var uploadPicLabel = document.querySelector('#upload-file');
var uploadOverlay = document.querySelector('.img-upload__overlay');
var closeOverlay = document.querySelector('.img-upload__cancel');
var previewPic = document.querySelector('.img-upload__preview');
var effectBar = document.querySelector('.img-upload__effect-level');
var effectsFieldset = document.querySelector('.img-upload__effects');
var commentField = document.querySelector('.text__description');
var hashtagsField = document.querySelector('.text__hashtags');
var pinLevel = document.querySelector('.effect-level__pin');
var effectLevelLine = document.querySelector('.effect-level__line');
var effectLevelDepth = document.querySelector('.effect-level__depth');

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var getRandomCommentator = function () {
  var randomCommentator = {};
  var randomComment = COMMENTS_LIST[Math.floor(Math.random() * COMMENTS_LIST.length)];
  var randomName = NAMES_LIST[Math.floor(Math.random() * NAMES_LIST.length)];
  randomCommentator.avatar = 'img/avatar-' + getRandomInt(1, 6) + '.svg';
  randomCommentator.message = randomComment;
  randomCommentator.name = randomName;
  return randomCommentator;
};

var generateComments = function () {
  var randomInt = getRandomInt(1, 26);
  var comments = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < randomInt; i++) {
    comments.push(getRandomCommentator(6));
  }
  return comments;
};

var generateData = function (count) {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    data.push(
        {
          url: 'photos/' + (i + 1) + '.jpg',
          likes: getRandomInt(1, 26),
          comments: generateComments()
        }
    );
  }
  return data;
};

var renderPhotos = function (array) {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (var k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
    var element = template.cloneNode(true);
    var item = array[k];
    element.querySelector('.picture__comments').textContent = item.comments.length;
    element.querySelector('.picture__likes').textContent = item.likes;
    element.querySelector('.picture__img').src = item.url;
    fragment.appendChild(element);
  }
  picturesDomElement.appendChild(fragment);
};

var onPopupEscPress = function (evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode === ESC_KEYCODE && document.activeElement !== commentField && document.activeElement !== hashtagsField) {
    closePicEditor();
  }
};

var openPicEditor = function () {
  uploadOverlay.classList.remove('hidden');
  document.addEventListener('keydown', onPopupEscPress);
};

var closePicEditor = function () {
  uploadOverlay.classList.add('hidden');
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', onPopupEscPress);
};

uploadPicLabel.addEventListener('change', function () {
  openPicEditor();
  changeOverlay();
});

closeOverlay.addEventListener('click', function () {
  closePicEditor();
});

var validateCommentLength = function () {
  if (commentField.value.length > 140) {
    commentField.style.border = 'thick solid red';
    commentField.setCustomValidity('The message is too long');
  } else {
    commentField.style.border = '';
    commentField.setCustomValidity('');
  }
};

var changeOverlay = function (percentage) {
  var checkedEffect = effectsFieldset.querySelector('input:checked');
  var filterValue;
  effectBar.classList.remove('hidden');
  switch (checkedEffect.value) {
    case 'chrome': filterValue = 'grayscale(' + percentage + ')'; break;
    case 'sepia': filterValue = 'sepia(' + percentage + ')'; break;
    case 'marvin': filterValue = 'invert(' + percentage + ')'; break;
    case 'phobos': filterValue = 'blur(' + percentage + 'px)'; break;
    case 'heat': filterValue = 'brightness(' + percentage + ')'; break;
    default: {
      filterValue = 'none';
      effectBar.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }
  pinLevel.style.left = percentage + '%';
  effectLevelDepth.style.width = percentage + '%';
  previewPic.style.filter = filterValue;
};

pinLevel.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var onMouseMove = function (moveEvt) {
    moveEvt.preventDefault();
    //get the total width of "effectLevelLine"
    var effectTotalWidth = effectLevelLine.offsetWidth;
    //get the start position of "effectLevelLine" from
    var effectLevelStart = effectLevelLine.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    //calculate the shift =  effectLevelLine position - effect-level__pin moveEvt.clientX
    var shift = effectTotalWidth - (effectLevelStart - moveEvt.clientX);
    //calculate percent
    var percentageLevel = shift / effectTotalWidth * 100;
    //to make sure that the pin is inside the effectLevelLine
    if (shift > 0 && shift < effectTotalWidth) {
      //apply 
      pinLevel.style.left = percentageLevel + '%';
      effectLevelDepth.style.width = percentageLevel + '%';
      changeOverlay(percentageLevel);
    }
  };
  var onMouseUp = function (upEvt) {
    upEvt.preventDefault();
    startCoords = upEvt.clientX;
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
  };
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
});

var photos = generateData(25);
renderPhotos(photos);
effectsFieldset.addEventListener('click', changeOverlay);
effectsFieldset.addEventListener('click', function () {
  changeOverlay(100);
});
commentField.addEventListener('change', validateCommentLength);
/**
 * Шкала регулирования глубины фильтра
 */
```

```css
.effect-level {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;

  width: 495px;
  height: 33px;

  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  white-space: nowrap;

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 33px;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.effect-level__value {
  display: none;
}

.effect-level__line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;

  height: 5px;

  font-size: 0;

  background-color: rgba(255, 231, 81, 0.4);

  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.effect-level__pin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  z-index: 1;

  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: -9px 0 0;

  background-color: #ffe753;
  border-radius: 50%;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);

  cursor: move;
}

.effect-level__depth {
  position: absolute;

  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: #ffe753;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>Кекстаграм</title>
  <style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>

    <!-- Фильтрация изображений от других пользователей -->
    <section class="img-filters  img-filters--inactive  container">
      <h2 class="img-filters__title  visually-hidden">Фильтр фотографий</h2>
      <form class="img-filters__form" action="index.html" method="get" autocomplete="off">
        <button type=button class="img-filters__button  img-filters__button--active" id="filter-popular">Популярные</button>
        <button type=button class="img-filters__button" id="filter-new">Новые</button>
        <button type=button class="img-filters__button" id="filter-discussed">Обсуждаемые</button>
      </form>
    </section>

    <!-- Контейнер для изображений от других пользователей -->
    <section class="pictures  container">
      <h2 class="pictures__title  visually-hidden">Фотографии других пользователей</h2>

      <!-- Поле для загрузки нового изображения на сайт -->
      <section class="img-upload">
        <div class="img-upload__wrapper">
          <h2 class="img-upload__title  visually-hidden">Загрузка фотографии</h2>
          <form class="img-upload__form" id="upload-select-image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

            <!-- Изначальное состояние поля для загрузки изображения -->
            <fieldset class="img-upload__start">
              <input type="file" id="upload-file" class="img-upload__input  visually-hidden" name="filename" required>
              <label for="upload-file" class="img-upload__label  img-upload__control">Загрузить</label>
            </fieldset>

            <!-- Форма редактирования изображения -->
            <div class="img-upload__overlay  hidden">
              <div class="img-upload__wrapper">
                <div class="img-upload__preview-container">

                  <!-- Изменение размера изображения -->
                  <fieldset class="img-upload__scale  scale">
                    <button type="button" class="scale__control  scale__control--smaller">Уменьшить</button>
                    <input type="text" class="scale__control  scale__control--value" value="55%" title="Image Scale" name="scale" readonly>
                    <button type="button" class="scale__control  scale__control--bigger">Увеличить</button>
                  </fieldset>

                  <!-- Предварительный просмотр изображения -->
                  <div class="img-upload__preview">
                    <img src="img/upload-default-image.jpg" alt="Предварительный просмотр фотографии">
                  </div>

                  <!-- Изменение глубины эффекта, накладываемого на изображение -->
                  <fieldset class="img-upload__effect-level  effect-level">
                    <input class="effect-level__value" type="number" name="effect-level" value="20">
                    <div class="effect-level__line">
                      <div class="effect-level__pin" tabindex="0">Кнопка изменения глубины эффекта фотографии</div>
                      <div class="effect-level__depth">Глубина эффекта фотографии</div>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>

                  <!-- Кнопка для закрытия формы редактирования изображения -->
                  <button type="reset" class="img-upload__cancel  cancel" id="upload-cancel">Закрыть</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Наложение эффекта на изображение -->
                <fieldset class="img-upload__effects  effects">
                  <ul class="effects__list">
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-none" value="none">
                      <label for="effect-none" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--none">Превью фото без эффекта</span>
                        Оригинал
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-chrome" value="chrome">
                      <label for="effect-chrome" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--chrome">Превью эффекта Хром</span>
                        Хром
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-sepia" value="sepia">
                      <label for="effect-sepia" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--sepia">Превью эффекта Сепия</span>
                        Сепия
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-marvin" value="marvin">
                      <label for="effect-marvin" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--marvin">Превью эффекта Марвин</span>
                        Марвин
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-phobos" value="phobos">
                      <label for="effect-phobos" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--phobos">Превью эффекта Фобос</span>
                        Фобос
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="effects__item">
                      <input type="radio" class="effects__radio  visually-hidden" name="effect" id="effect-heat" value="heat" checked>
                      <label for="effect-heat" class="effects__label">
                        <span class="effects__preview  effects__preview--heat">Превью эффекта Зной</span>
                        Зной
                      </label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </fieldset>

                <!-- Добавление хэш-тегов и комментария к изображению -->
                <fieldset class="img-upload__text text">
                  <input class="text__hashtags" name="hashtags" placeholder="#хэш-тег">
                  <textarea class="text__description" name="description" placeholder="Ваш комментарий..."></textarea>
                </fieldset>

                <!-- Кнопка для отправки данных на сервер -->
                <button type="submit" class="img-upload__submit" id="upload-submit">Опубликовать</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!-- Здесь будут изображения других пользователей -->

    </section>

    <!-- Полноэкранный показ изображения -->
    <section class="big-picture  overlay  hidden">
      <h2 class="big-picture__title  visually-hidden">Просмотр фотографии</h2>
      <div class="big-picture__preview">

        <!-- Просмотр изображения -->
        <div class="big-picture__img">
          <img src="img/logo-background-3.jpg" alt="Девушка в купальнике" width="600" height="600">
        </div>

        <!-- Информация об изображении. Подпись, комментарии, количество лайков -->
        <div class="big-picture__social  social">
          <div class="social__header">
            <img class="social__picture" src="img/avatar-1.svg" alt="Аватар автора фотографии" width="35" height="35">
            <p class="social__caption">Тестим новую камеру! =)</p>
            <p class="social__likes">Нравится <span class="likes-count">356</span></p>
          </div>

          <!-- Комментарии к изображению -->
          <div class="social__comment-count">5 из <span class="comments-count">125</span> комментариев</div>
          <ul class="social__comments">
            <li class="social__comment">
              <img class="social__picture" src="img/avatar-4.svg" alt="Аватар комментатора фотографии" width="35" height="35">
              <p class="social__text">Мега фото! Просто обалдеть. Как вам так удалось?</p>
            </li>
            <li class="social__comment">
              <img class="social__picture" src="img/avatar-3.svg" alt="Аватар комментатора фотографии" width="35" height="35">
               <p class="social__text">Да это фоташоп!!!!!!!!</p>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Кнопка для загрузки новой порции комментариев -->
          <button type="button" class="social__comments-loader  comments-loader">Загрузить еще</button>

          <!-- Форма для отправки комментария -->
          <div class="social__footer">
            <img class="social__picture" src="img/avatar-6.svg" alt="Аватар комментатора фотографии" width="35" height="35">
            <input type="text" class="social__footer-text" placeholder="Ваш комментарий...">
            <button type="button" class="social__footer-btn" name="button">Отправить</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Кнопка для выхода из полноэкранного просмотра изображения -->
        <button type="reset" class="big-picture__cancel  cancel" id="picture-cancel">Закрыть</button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer class="page-footer  container">
    <div class="page-footer__wrapper">
      <div class="page-footer__copyright  copyright">
        <a class="copyright__link  copyright__link--image" href="https://htmlacademy.ru/intensive/javascript"><img src="img/htmla-logo.svg" width="130" height="45" alt="HTML Academy"></a>
        <p>Сделано в <a class="copyright__link  copyright__link--text" href="https://htmlacademy.ru/intensive/javascript">HTML Academy</a> &copy; 2018</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="page-footer__contacts  contacts">
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/htmlacademy_ru" class="contacts__link  contacts__link--twitter">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/htmlacademy/" class="contacts__link  contacts__link--instagram">Instagtam</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/htmlacademy" class="contacts__link  contacts__link--facebook">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://vk.com/htmlacademy" class="contacts__link  contacts__link--vk">VK</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Шаблон изображения случайного пользователя -->
  <template id="picture">
    <a href="#" class="picture">
      <img class="picture__img" src="" width="182" height="182" alt="Случайная фотография">
      <p class="picture__info">
        <span class="picture__comments"></span>
        <span class="picture__likes"></span>
      </p>
    </a>
  </template>

  <!-- Сообщение с ошибкой загрузки изображения -->
  <template id="error">
    <section class="error">
      <div class="error__inner">
        <h2 class="error__title">Ошибка загрузки файла</h2>
        <div class="error__buttons">
          <button type="button" class="error__button">Попробовать снова</button>
          <button type="button" class="error__button">Загрузить другой файл</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </template>

  <!-- Сообщение об успешной загрузке изображения -->
  <template id="success">
    <section class="success">
      <div class="success__inner">
        <h2 class="success__title">Изображение успешно загружено</h2>
        <button type="button" class="success__button">Круто!</button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </template>

  <!-- Экран загрузки изображения -->
  <template id="messages">
    <div class="img-upload__message  img-upload__message--loading">Загружаем...</div>
  </template>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```